# Bigdata Project Scalable Architecture

Tags: architecture, nosql, bigdata, scalability

I have a background in web development and I'm totally new to bigdata solutions, so not sure if there are standard approaches for the projects like below. Let me first describe the request.

There are ~100k clients (data providers), their task is to gather information from some external systems. These data providers store data in different formats, but there are no more than 50 different formats for all ~100k data providers. The nature of the data is about efficiency (and maybe outage) of external systems.

The idea is to have a general dashboard with analytics for all external systems. So different formats should be converted into some common format at some level.
It is also important to have data in real time, so that if outage happens in one of external systems, it should be alerted pretty quickly in the central dashboard (1 min refresh time should be ok).

Also:

1. The system must be scalable, because we might have 500k clients instead of 100k after some time
2. In the future, the system should support some machine learning to predict inefficiencies/outages based on some data and warn in advance
3. Central dashboard should be a Web based solution and show data in almost real time
4. There should be automatic archive of some old data
5. Central dashboard should be fast enough to get and group data from all the external systems

I need help to understand how to architect the system and some advice with what tools should I learn more about. The concern is that regular SQL database might not cope with 100k data packets sent every minute. So I started looking at NoSQL, but there are many different options and I don't know the differences.

Here are more specific questions that I have:

1. What would be the best database for such scenario? (Hadoop, MongoDb, ...?)
2. What should be the server infrastructure? Not sure, maybe it should be just a cluster of load balanced servers, that are processing the data requests from the data providers, then converting to common format and putting on the message queue. Some other process will read from the queue and write into the database.
3. On what level should I convert the data from different formats to a common format? Should I have different clients sending data to different servers depending on the format or should the server take care of converting logic, or maybe should I force clients to convert data to a common format (maybe not a good idea because there are quite many clients and not so many different formats)
4. Are there any existing tools for machine learning and analytics that can be used?
5. Are there any existing tools in this architecture that could be used for caching or other ways to optimize performance for central dashboard?
6. Should I look for cloud based solutions like MS Azure?
7. For now, I'm thinking about the architecture as described on the screenshot below, let me please know if you think there are any issues, if it's not scalable or something else?
   [image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer all questions, but i will tell you my opinion at whatever i can and i am certain of.

SQL vs NoSQL. This is a critical choice. Make sure you select properly because those are entirely different architectures and NoSQL has certain limitations, moslty ACID and relational concept. Make sure those limitations are not affecting your business. SQL on the other hand has no such limitations and 'regular SQL database might not cope with...' is not true at all because with standard relational SQL all is about what you pay is what you get. There are certainly RDBMS that handle not *5 but *500 the data you describe but they are not cheap - that is another story.

Data in common format. This is a trap case. My opinion is that you should stay out of database prior to any format conversion to the standard format. You need 1 global standard format that encapsulates all 50 (later 150 with version variations!!!) present different formats. And you need some logic somewhere (not in the database for sure) to convert to the standard format. This should be done at application level without db involvement. Burdening the db with this will not scale well nor will be maintainable as easily as with some application solution for this task.

Azure is scalable and gets you off infrastructure concerns plus high availability. However it has its price. IT worth checking out for sure.